# unable to get index in json array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am trying to get json array in codeigniter with index but unable to get the expected result.
Please some one guide me to make a json array including indexes shown in the following expected array.

I tried the following code

***my Controller code***

```
public function returnDepartments()
  {
    $departments = $this->search_model->departmentsjson();
    $return_json = array();

    foreach ($departments as $department) {
      $return_json [] = [
        'id'=>$department->id,
        'departmentTitle' => $department->name,
        'icon'=> base_url().'public/contents/img/groups/'.$department->image,
        'allSubjects'=> $department->courses,
        'lecturesCount' => $department->links
      ];
    }

   $json_array= str_replace(array("[","]"),"",htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(json_encode(array('departments'=>$return_json))),ENT_NOQUOTES));
   echo $json_array;

  }
```

***my Model Code***

```
public function departmentsjson()
  {
    $this->db->select('gp.*,count(gc.id) as "courses",count(cl.id) as "links"');
    $this->db->from('group_departments gp');
    $this->db->join('group_courses gc','gp.id = gc.group_id','left');
    $this->db->join('course_links cl','gc.id = cl.course_id','left')->group_by('gp.id');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```

*** getting the json***

```
{
  "departments":{ "0": {
    "id": "1",
    "departmentTitle": "Basic &amp; Health Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/basic_n_helth.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "10608",
    "lecturesCount": "10594"
  },
  "1":{
    "id": "2",
    "departmentTitle": "Applied Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/applied_sciense.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "3806",
    "lecturesCount": "3800"
  },
  "2":{
    "id": "3",
    "departmentTitle": "Social Sciences &amp; Humanities",
    "icon": public/contents/img/groups/social_sciences.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "26365",
    "lecturesCount": "26322"
  }
}
}
```

***Expecting Json***

```
{
  "departments": {
    "id": "1",
    "departmentTitle": "Basic &amp; Health Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/basic_n_helth.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "10608",
    "lecturesCount": "10594"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "departmentTitle": "Applied Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/applied_sciense.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "3806",
    "lecturesCount": "3800"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "departmentTitle": "Social Sciences &amp; Humanities",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/social_sciences.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "26365",
    "lecturesCount": "26322"
  }
}
```

Please guide me to resolve the issue . How can I get my expected json array

Comment: In Expecting Json i guess it should be array of objects "departments": [{ },{ }]..

Comment: You shouldn't be using any `str_replace()` on the JSON result, you are more likely to cause problems than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that both getting and expected json are valid.

Your **getting json** should be

```
{"departments": {
    "id": "1",
    "departmentTitle": "Basic &amp; Health Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/basic_n_helth.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "10608",
    "lecturesCount": "10594"
  }, ……
}
```

Because only `[` and `]` can be removed

Your **expected json** should be something like

```
{
"departments": [ {…},{…} …]
}
```

So, Just remove the `str_replace`

```
$json_array= json_encode(array("departments" => $return_json));
echo $json_array;
```

**Edit:** If you need something like following

```
{ "departments":{ "0":{....}, "1":{...} } }
```

You can try

```
$json_array= json_encode(array("departments" => (object) $return_json));
echo $json_array;
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. my required json format is 
```{
"departments":{
"0":{....},
"1":{...}
}
}```
how can i add the index of "0" , "1" etc in the json .

Answer (score 0):

Expecting JSON

```
{
  "departments": {
    "id": "1",
    "departmentTitle": "Basic &amp; Health Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/basic_n_helth.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "10608",
    "lecturesCount": "10594"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "departmentTitle": "Applied Sciences",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/applied_sciense.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "3806",
    "lecturesCount": "3800"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "departmentTitle": "Social Sciences &amp; Humanities",
    "icon": "public/contents/img/groups/social_sciences.jpg",
    "allSubjects": "26365",
    "lecturesCount": "26322"
  }
}
```

Valid JSON

```
{
   "departments":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "departmentTitle":"Basic & Health Sciences",
         "icon":"public/contents/img/groups/basic_n_helth.jpg",
         "allSubjects":"10608",
         "lecturesCount":"10594"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "departmentTitle":"Applied Sciences",
         "icon":"public/contents/img/groups/applied_sciense.jpg",
         "allSubjects":"3806",
         "lecturesCount":"3800"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "departmentTitle":"Social Sciences & Humanities",
         "icon":"public/contents/img/groups/social_sciences.jpg",
         "allSubjects":"26365",
         "lecturesCount":"26322"
      }
   ]
}
```

And remove `str_replace`.

Your expected JSON is invalid.